# Swift 3 - kAudioFilePropertyMagicCookieData unsupported on AudioFile

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swift3, core-audio

The function `AudioFileGetPropertyInfo` returns `'pty?'` (which is equal to `kAudioFileUnsupportedPropertyError`) when trying to get the size of an audio files magic cookie.

What could be the cause here? Doesn't an `AudioFileID` support the `AudioFileGetPropertyInfo` property?

The function `AudioFileGetPropertyInfo` was called in this context:

```
func copyEncoderCookieToQueue(file: AudioFileID, queue: AudioQueueRef) {
    var error: OSStatus
    var propertySize: UInt32 = 0

    error = AudioFileGetPropertyInfo(file, kAudioFilePropertyMagicCookieData, &propertySize, nil)
    checkError(error, msg: "Couldn't get property size.")

    // More code
}
```

First I was thinking, that the audio file might not contain an magic cookie, but wouldn't the function return zero as it's size then?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1318/_index.html

Comment: @matt So I'll get `kAudioFileUnsupportedPropertyError` if no copy is found? If you'd like to post that as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: All I did was suggest reading the docs. If you've solved the problem, feel free to provide your own answer.

Comment: @matt The final `else` catches the error case with an comment: `//OK if audio doesn't need magic cookie data`, but I'm still unsure about whether I'll definitely get an error if no cookie data exists. How would you interpret the `err != noErr` case? The first comment says `Get Magic Cookie info(if exists)`, but how do I figure out if a magic cookie exists?

Comment: "How would you interpret the `err != noErr` case?" You mean, the `else` of the `if err == noErr`? That means this sound format doesn't involve a magic cookie. That's what the example in that doc is showing you. So I think that means you can count on that: you got an error, so there's no magic cookie involved here.